# Sound in smartphone from headset bluetooth

Tags: audio, microphone, headset

Is it possible that headset a bluetooth microphone to send audio to phones all the time? I would like to make live YouTube and facebook not using the built-in microphone only from bluetooth headset

Answer (score 0):

My Galaxy s4 will record the audio track of a video using a Bluetooth headset.

Comment: i have samsung A3 2016 and-6 i can do this , when i start live stream still i have bulid-in microphone....